# Safe to add a class attribute to the HTML element via the theme?

Tags: theming, 8

In Drupal 8 is it safe to manually add a class attribute to the HTML element in the theme's html.html.twig file?

```
<html{{ html_attributes }} class="no-js">
```

Its working fine for me but I don't know if there are some instances where Drupal would want to add a class as part of html_attributes? If so then presumably my output would be this:

```
<html class="drupals-class" class="no-js">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `.addclass()`:

```
<html{{ html_attributes.addClass('no-js') }}>
```

That would prevent the output in the example from your question and the result will be:

```
<html class="drupals-class no-js">
```