# IE conditional comments for HTML class?

Tags: theming, 8

I need to have the following html classes with IE conditional comments in my Drupal 8 site:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie10 lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie10"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!-->
<html class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Ideally I would use html_attributes.addClass see this question: [Safe to add a class attribute to the HTML element via the theme?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/215285/safe-to-add-a-class-attribute-to-the-html-element-via-the-theme)

I tried this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>      <html{{ html_attributes.addClass('no-js lt-ie10 lt-ie9') }}> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>         <html{{ html_attributes.addClass('no-js lt-ie10') }}> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!-->
<html{{ html_attributes.addClass('no-js') }}>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

But it seems once you add a class to html_attributes then its printed every time, so my final instance which should only have a class of `no-js` instead has this:

```
no-js lt-ie10 lt-ie9 no-js lt-ie10 no-js
```

Comment: addClass I guess should add only once.. I didn't know that: (

Comment: This behaviour is a feature, so the code is working as expected, you just need to do things differently to get the required result for this use case (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to print the class attributes separately, and use the `without` twig filter, then hard code the IE stuff, e.g.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]> <html{{ html_attributes|without('class') }} class="{{ html_attributes.class }} lt-ie10 lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>    <html{{ html_attributes|without('class') }} class="{{ html_attributes.class }} lt-ie10"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!-->
<html{{ html_attributes.addClass('no-js') }}>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

- https://www.drupal.org/node/1823416
- https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/filters-modifying-variables-in-twig-templates